# Angularjs binding to Ajax return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, azure-mobile-services

I have an angularjs app with the following factory method that does live API call:

```
//Return SP json by SPID
    azureMobileClient.getSPjsonBySPID = function (callback, spid)
    {
        azureMobileClient.azureMSC.invokeApi("get_spjson_byspid", {
            parameters: {
                spid: spid
            },
            method: "get"
        }).done(function (results) {
            //console.log(results.result);

            callback(results.result);
        }, function (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        });
    }
```

And I have the following controller's method that consume it

```
$scope.getSPName = function (spid)
    {

        console.log("SPID:", spid);

        var returnedName;

        AzureMobileClient.getSPjsonBySPID(function (item)
        {
            console.log("item.fullname:", item.fullname);
            returnedName = item.fullname;


        }, spid);

        return returnedName;
    }
```

And this is how I am currently attempting to bind the returned `item.fullname` in my view (inside ng-repeat):

```
<p>
{{getSPName(t.parsedjsondata.SPId)}}
</p>
```

The problem is that the binding does not work although I do see the value of the console.log() with the correct `item.fullname`. I am guessing that this has to do with the delay of the API call and I need to insert `$scope.$apply()` somewhere but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You really should try using promises on this ($q).  Here is example code on how to use $q.defer(): https://medium.com/javascript-jquery-angular-firebase-and-mongodb/angular-s-q-defer-example-78867ecfa7d8

Answer (score 2):

There are some bad practices in your code. Some suggestions:

1. Use promises, i.e. $q in your factory methods.
2. Try not to use expensive functions in your expressions {{}}. They are evaluated often as part of Angular's dirty checking process.

One way to solve your problem is to change your Angular service function to return a promise:

```
azureMobileClient.getSPjsonBySPID = function (spid)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    azureMobileClient.azureMSC.invokeApi("get_spjson_byspid", {
        parameters: {
            spid: spid
        },
        method: "get"
    }).done(function (results) {
        //console.log(results.result);
        deferred.resolve(results.result);
    }, function (error) {
        alert(error.message);
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then in your controller do something like:

```
$scope.spName = null;
azureMobileClient.getSPjsonBySPID(spid).then(function(item){
    $scope.spName = item.fullname;
}, function(error) {
    // Show error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, lookslike you are binding wrongly {{}} use variable to resolve in value.

```
<p>
{{SPName}}
</p>

$scope.getSPName = function (spid)
    {

        console.log("SPID:", spid);

        var returnedName;

        return AzureMobileClient.getSPjsonBySPID(function (item)
        {
            console.log("item.fullname:", item.fullname);
            returnedName = item.fullname;
            return returnedName;
        }, spid);


    }
$scope.SPName = $scope.getSPName(t.parsedjsondata.SPId)
```

Comment: Still does not work. I can see the value of item.fullname being retrieved in the console.log but it is not being binded to the view. I have am sure that is because the value is retrieved from a live server with some delay and I need to call $scope.$applay() somehow but I am not sure how to call it with a 'return' statement in my method